# Ad connect - what data from Teams will be missing

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

My organisation use Active Directory on-premise (windows server 2012). We also use Office 365 E1.
Logins are different. We add accounts independly.

Now we are however are thinking about using Ad Connect, but we have some concerns.

Will we lose any data on Teams after integration?
Will our users be able to access data previously attached to theirs Azure Active Directory account?
How can we match AAD users with on-premise AD. It uses aliases?

Answer (score 0):

Following MS documents should give a head start for your requirement.

[How objects and credentials are synchronized in an Azure Active Directory Domain Services managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization)

[Integrate on-premises AD with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/)

[Integrate on-premises AD domains with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/azure-ad)

[Azure AD Connect: When you have an existing tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant)

[Microsoft 365 integration with on-premises environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-integration?view=o365-worldwide)